# Pass objects from JS to controller and razor mail template

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, 2sxc

I've been trying to isolate the mail feature from 2sxc mobius app to implement it on my own 2sxc projects, but so far I've only been successful on passing string, string dictionary. If I try to use the default string,object it gives several compiling not very specific errors.

Here's what I have working right now:

View:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label for="testfield">Test field</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="testfield" value="">
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <button id="saveData" type="button" onclick="saveMailData()">Guardar dados</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/js/2sxc.api.min.js" data-enableoptimizations="100"></script>

<script>
function saveMailData() {

    var newItem = {
        "user": "@Dnn.User.Username",
        "testfield": $("#testfield").val()
    };

    $2sxc(@Dnn.Module.ModuleID).webApi.post("Form/ProcessForm", {}, newItem, true)
    .success(function() {
        alert("Success");
    })
    .error(function() {
        alert("Error");
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
using DotNetNuke.Security;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using System.Web.Http;
using ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Compilation;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Mail;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class FormController : SxcApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void ProcessForm([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> contactFormRequest)
    {

    string mailFrom = "x@x.pt";
    string mailTo = "y@y.com";
    string mailCc = "z@z.com";
    string mailReply = "w@w.pt";
    string mailSubject = "THIS IS THE SUBJECT " + contactFormRequest["user"].ToString();
    string mailbody = "<table><tr><td>THIS IS THE MESSAGE BODY</td></tr></table>";

    var ownerMailEngine = TemplateInstance("testmailtemplate.cshtml");
    var ownerBody = ownerMailEngine.Message(contactFormRequest, this).ToString();
    var ownerSubj = ownerMailEngine.Subject(contactFormRequest, this);

    Mail.SendMail(mailFrom, mailTo, mailCc, "", mailReply, MailPriority.Normal, ownerSubj, MailFormat.Html, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, ownerBody, new string[0], "", "", "", "", false);
    }

    private dynamic TemplateInstance(string fileName)
    {
        var compiledType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(System.IO.Path.Combine("~", App.Path, fileName));
        object objectValue = null;
        if (compiledType != null)
        {
            objectValue = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(Activator.CreateInstance(compiledType));
            return ((dynamic)objectValue);
        }
        throw new Exception("Error while creating mail template instance.");
    }
}
```

And template:

```
@helper Message(Dictionary<string,string> request, ToSic.SexyContent.IAppAndDataHelpers context)
{
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Website contact form request</h1>
        <p>Key/Value:</p>
        <table width="100%">
            @foreach (var item in request)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%"><b>@item.Key.ToString()</b></td>
                    <td>@item.Value.ToString()</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
}

@functions {
    public string Subject(dynamic request, dynamic helpers) {
        return "this is a subject from template";
    }
}
```

I would really like to avoid using dynamic to receive data (it's a nightmare for beginners), so can you help me to properly pass data as objects (string,object) from JS to controller and from controller to razor template?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use  you'll somehow assume that the system will correctly convert these to number, date and so forth. This will usually not be reliable and cause a lot of side-effects. For example, a number from an input-field would be a string in the browser, so it would also arrive as a string in the server.

Dates would be worse: they would be treated as strings - and no automatic detection would turn them into dates, because the JSON format used by AJAX-calls has no standard for dates.

So basically both numbers and dates would give you no benefit if you tried an object approach (as it wouldn't automatically have the other type). So I'm not sure if there is any additional benefit. Is there another reason to do this?